# delete tabs that added from copy-paste in emacs

Tags: text, emacs, indentation

when i copy text in emacs sometimes it breaks the indentation adding extra tabs. for example if i copy the output from the command

```
curl api.test.org | python -mjson.tool
```

and paste it in the emacs the json format breaks.

i am looking for a way to select the whole text and delete the tabs. A small piece of this looks like this

```
»       »       »       »       ················"settings":·[$
»       »       »       »       »       »       ················{$                                                                                                                                                                           
»       »       »       »       »       »       »       »       ····················"key":·"+ASSET_1",$
»       »       »       »       »       »       »       »       »       »       ························"value":·"runtest-files-%HDD_1%.tar.gz"$
```

i tried delete-indentation but it is something different. And the untabify will just replave the tabs with spaces. Any ideas?

Comment: select the region, `M-x` `replace-string` first enter `C-q` <tab> for the target string, and empty string for replacement

Comment: @Rorschach: Please consider posting that as an answer, to help others. Comments can be deleted at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from @Rorschach
I copy-paste his solution
select the region, `M-x replace-string` first enter `C-q`  for the target string, and empty string for replacement